# Best practice for implementing a "template of something that users can join" solution in a DB

Tags: database, oop, database-design

I'm looking for the best practice for designing a database schema where someone can post a template of something (for example how a certain 'schedule' looks like) and then user can 'join' that template but change stuff from it without of course changing the original template.

I'll add an example, as i'm not the best in explaining something in text form. (and english is not my native language)

Say you have 4 tables:

- Schedule
- Day
- Task
- TaskRule

A schedule can have N days, a day can have N tasks, and a task finally can have N taskRules.
A user will 'join' this schedule via a join table (user_schedule that has the user id and the schedule_id).

Now the problem is that when a user changes something from the template (lets say he adds a few taskRules or he removes a task) the schedule will change for everyone that is connected to it.

My question is what is the best practice to handle this? I really can't see how this can be done other then row duplication which is not my favorite thing to do.

Edit: This schema means he will join the template schedule and choose 1 of 2 things (namely to change it or not to change it, if he doesn't change it duplication is clearly redundant)

Comment: looks like a versioning system... (CVS, SVN, GIT, Mercural, et al.)...
or you mean that the user now has his own callendar?

Comment: His own calendar basically, but one that is based of a template (schedule in this case).

Answer (score 1):

my suggestion is:

- Rename task to task_template.
- Make a table called task with template_id, user_id and all the other fields in task_template.
- When adding data only insert the differences in the new table.
- When you load the data, you read the template_id and override with what is not empty in the row.

the main problem here is that you are trying to achieve inheritance/extension/prototyping in an sql database...

Comment: just tought about storing the whole json in the database... bad idea

Comment: The problem is that these few tables was just an abstraction of the real problem. In total 4-5 table values can be changed per given 'template' so while you could make separate 'user' join tables for them, the problem would be decide which one to take.

This is actually a problem i face with php, mysql and doctrine as ORM.

Answer (score 1):

You have different options:

1. Copy all the data. This is easy to do, but duplicates tons of data which might be a problem, especially when modifications are the exception.
2. A variation would be to normally just link to the template and only copy it, when changes where actually made. This increases the complexity of the code but might save tons of data. Also this might be applied to each table seperately.
3. Link the data + changes: You have only a reference to the schedule as proposed in your question and then keep track of all the changes made by a specific user. Basically as SparK describes. But not that you might need to handle deletes and changes as well. This is ways more complex to handle, but might even handle changes to the schedule after the "join" happened.